Error "No catalog entry found for partition ID ..."
When trying to delete disabled index or enable the same disabled index on one heavily utilised table, I am getting an error:
No catalog entry found for partition ID 72057594967228416 in database 6. The metadata is inconsistent. Run DBCC CHECKDB to check for a metadata corruption.

The database has different filegroups (one for table, one for indexes, ...) but no partitioning, no partition schemes, no partition functions. I can flawlessly create different index in the same filegroup with no error.
DBCC CHECKDB('myDB') WITH ALL_ERRORMSGS, NO_INFOMSGS returns exactly 0 errors.
My question: is the metadata damaged as in this case: Question DBA stack exchange or is there a way out?
Thanks!

-- Step 1: Run DBCC CHECKDB
DBCC CHECKDB('myDB') WITH ALL_ERRORMSGS, NO_INFOMSGS;

-- Step 2: Run DBCC CHECKCATALOG
DBCC CHECKCATALOG('myDB') WITH NO_INFOMSGS;

-- Step 3: Investigate the specific partition ID
SELECT * 
FROM sys.partitions 
WHERE partition_id = 72057594967228416;

-- Step 4: Check for disabled indexes
SELECT 
    i.name AS index_name,
    i.type_desc,
    i.is_disabled,
    p.partition_id
FROM 
    sys.indexes i
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.object_id AND i.index_id = p.index_id
WHERE 
    i.object_id = OBJECT_ID('YourTableName');

-- Step 5: Try to rebuild the index
ALTER INDEX [YourIndexName] ON [YourTableName] REBUILD;

-- Step 6: Drop and recreate the index
DROP INDEX [YourIndexName] ON [YourTableName];

-- Step 7: Check for orphaned metadata
SELECT * 
FROM sys.allocation_units 
WHERE container_id = 72057594967228416;

-- If orphaned entries are found, you may need to delete them carefully:
-- DELETE FROM sys.allocation_units WHERE container_id = 72057594967228416;

-- Always ensure you have a full database backup before making such changes.

